# Swift 2 Regex unexpected behaviour

Tags: regex, swift, swift2

I'm trying to extract information from a HTML string but I am having unexpected results. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
let html: NSString? = "<tbody><tr><td sortkey=\"20151003\">03 Oct 2015</td><td>8,852.61</td><td>1,383.68</td><td>Text</td></tr><tr><td sortkey=\"20151004\">04 Oct 2015</td><td>2,577.14</td><td>282.49</td><td>Text</td></tr></tbody>"

let rowPattern = "<tr>\\s*<td s.*?<\\/tr>"
let rowRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: rowPattern, options: [])
let rowMatches = rowRegex.matchesInString(String(html), options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, html!.length))

for rowMatch in rowMatches {
    let rowString: NSString = html!.substringWithRange(rowMatch.resultByAdjustingRangesWithOffset(-9).range)

    print(rowString)

    let valPattern = "<td>(.*?)<\\/td>|<td.*?\"(.*?)\">.*?<\\/td>"
    let valRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: valPattern, options: [])
    let valMatches = valRegex.matchesInString(String(rowString), options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, rowString.length))

    for valMatch in valMatches {
        print(valMatch.rangeAtIndex(1))
        // let value = rowString.substringWithRange(valMatch.rangeAtIndex(1))
        // print(value)
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
<tr><td sortkey="20151003">03 Oct 2015</td><td>8,852.61</td><td>1,383.68</td><td>Text</td></tr>
(9223372036854775807,0)
(47,8)
(64,8)
(81,4)
```

First off, note that I need to offset the range for the rowMatch by -9 to get the correct result. I have no idea why that is the case.

Second, the range returned for the first match is (9223372036854775807,0) which is obviously not correct and throws an error. Again, I don't understand what's going wrong here but I suspect it might be an issue with my regex pattern. The other ranges are correct.

For info, the expected output of `print(value)` is:

```
20151003
8,852.61
1,383.68
Text
```

**Edit:**

After further experimentation I found the following:

`valMatches[0].rangeAtIndex(2)` gives the correct range for the first match but `valMatches[0].rangeAtIndex(1)` is required for the rest. I'm not sure if this is the correct behaviour or if it is a bug as suggested by @t4nhpt in his answer below. Either way, if anyone can explain what's going on it would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first problem** is that `let html: NSString? = "..."` is an *optional*,
and therefore `String(html)` evaluates to

```
Optional(...)
```

The mysterious offset `9` is the length of "Optional(" :)

To fix that, you can either unwrap `String(html!)` or declare `html`
as a non-optional. In either case, `resultByAdjustingRangesWithOffset(-9)` is not necessary.

---

The **second problem** is that you have two capture groups in your 
pattern:

```
let valPattern = "<td>(.*?)<\\/td>|<td.*?\"(.*?)\">.*?<\\/td>"
```

`<td>8,852.61</td>` matches the first alternative, therefore the
first capture group matches `8,852.61`, so that
`rangeAtIndex(1)`is set to the range of that string, and 
`rangeAtIndex(2)` is set to `(NSNotFound, 0)`.

`<td sortkey="20151003">03 Oct 2015</td>` matches the second
alternative, therefore `rangeAtIndex(2)` is set to the
range of `20151003` and `rangeAtIndex(1)` is `(NSNotFound, 0)`.

`NSNotFound` is defined as `Int.max` and that is `2^63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807` on a 64-bit platform.

---

Putting it all together, this gives the expected results:

```
let html: NSString = "<tbody><tr><td sortkey=\"20151003\">03 Oct 2015</td><td>8,852.61</td><td>1,383.68</td><td>Text</td></tr><tr><td sortkey=\"20151004\">04 Oct 2015</td><td>2,577.14</td><td>282.49</td><td>Text</td></tr></tbody>"

let rowPattern = "<tr>\\s*<td s.*?<\\/tr>"
let rowRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: rowPattern, options: [])
let rowMatches = rowRegex.matchesInString(String(html), options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, html.length))

for rowMatch in rowMatches {
    let rowString: NSString = html.substringWithRange(rowMatch.range)

    print("rowString=\(rowString)")

    let valPattern = "<td>(.*?)<\\/td>|<td.*?\"(.*?)\">.*?<\\/td>"
    let valRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: valPattern, options: [])
    let valMatches = valRegex.matchesInString(String(rowString), options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, rowString.length))

    for valMatch in valMatches {
        if valMatch.rangeAtIndex(1).location != NSNotFound {
            let value = rowString.substringWithRange(valMatch.rangeAtIndex(1))
            print(value)
        }
        if valMatch.rangeAtIndex(2).location != NSNotFound {
            let value = rowString.substringWithRange(valMatch.rangeAtIndex(2))
            print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
rowString=<tr><td sortkey="20151003">03 Oct 2015</td><td>8,852.61</td><td>1,383.68</td><td>Text</td></tr>
20151003
8,852.61
1,383.68
Text
rowString=<tr><td sortkey="20151004">04 Oct 2015</td><td>2,577.14</td><td>282.49</td><td>Text</td></tr>
20151004
2,577.14
282.49
Text
```

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense now! I'm new to swift and getting my head around optionals etc is proving quite a challenge! Any idea why the regex matches are at different indexes? Not a big deal since I can work around it but I'm still curious!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the well explained answer!

Answer (score 1):

It seem a bug when join two patterns. You can split your pattern into two part, find two `[NSTextCheckingResult]` and then concatenate them together. Cheat, haha.

```
  // let valPattern = "<td>(.*?)<\\/td>|<td.*?\"(.*?)\">.*?<\\/td>"
  let valPattern1 = "<td.*?\"(.*?)\">.*?<\\/td>"
  let valPattern2 = "<td>(.*?)<\\/td>"
  var valRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: valPattern1, options: [])
  var valMatches1 = valRegex.matchesInString(String(rowString), options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, rowString.length))
  valRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: valPattern2, options: [])
  let valMatches2 = valRegex.matchesInString(String(rowString), options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, rowString.length))

  valMatches1 += valMatches2

  for valMatch in valMatches1 {
       ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to figure it out using one pattern though as described in the edit to my question. Would be interested to know why that is the case though!